# Error de entidades (base de datos incluida) en aplicación de escritorio instalada

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, windows-forms, windows-installer

Buen día tengan, les comento que tengo una aplicación y la quiero convertir a un instalador, ya lo hice de dos formas.

1. Publicación del proyecto de la aplicación
2. Asistente en Visual Studio (Proyecto instalador)

El primero sin problemas, es un instalador sencillo bueno solo no puedes agregarle acceso directo e iconos personalizados.

El segundo funciona bien la instalación y todo a excepción de las funciones a base de datos.

mi forma de conectarme a base de datos es esta:
1. Tengo la cadena de conexión en el App.Config
2. Tengo una clase modelo del tipo DbContext del cual se comunica con otros modelos y hace las operaciones de base de datos.

```
 namespace LSK_REST_Desktop8.Models
{

public class LSK_DBContext:DbContext
{
    public LSK_DBContext() : base("LSK_DBContext") { }

    public DbSet<Configuraciones> Configuraciones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Empleado> Empleados { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ingredientes> Ingredientes { get; set; }
    ....
```

El instalador rápido no me da error pero el instalador por medio de proyecto no me deja crear, eliminar o actualizar salvo que si me deja consultar y eso que los compare y tienen los mismos archivos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los archivos de Default Company son del instalador

Cada que hago algo con base de datos(excepto consultas) me arroja este error:

> Ocurrio un error. An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exceptions for details

¿Alguien me puede decir que pasa en este tipo de casos?

Comment: ¿Has probado a ver que te dice la propiedad InnerException de la excepción? El mismo compilador te dice que ahí tienes mas detalles.

Comment: ya revise el inner, me dice que la base de datos es solo de lectura: "Failed to update database because the database is read-only"